# Excel - find and replace images?

Tags: microsoft-excel, images, microsoft-excel-2010, find-and-replace

I exported a huge page from confluence into excel and it has a few columns that contain images. I need to convert them into text before I do another transition but this would be totally killing to do this manually - there are so many of them.

Is there a way to find and replace images in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There truly is no way to do this in a simple "find & replace" fashion. Every image (even if one image is copy-pasted all over) will have its unique name within Excel. Unless you are ready to figure the alikeness along them with regular expressions or something.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to find images within Excel.  For example:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
  For Inx = 1 To .Shapes.Count
    Debug.Print "Name " & .Shapes(Inx).Name
  Next
End With
```

will find and display the name of every image in Sheet1.

But you want to convert them to text.  What sort of images are they?  What about the image do you want to convert to text?

I find it difficult to believe it would not be easier to re-export from Confluence as text.

Comment: well, the problem is that even if there are 10 copy-paste images in there, each will have its unique name anyway. So the whole find & replace idea does not seem possible.